# Fails to save file (image) in some devices

Tags: android, ioexception, android-file

In my application I'll download an Image from a url and write it into an external storage. It works on 2 out of 3 devices I've tested and failed on 3rd. The first 2 are LG and Lenovo devices (unrooted) and the 3rd one is a Lenovo (rooted). Now when I save the file using below code everything works fine on first 2 devices but throws an:

**IOException: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)**

while creating the file. I don't have any illegal character in my file name as it is shown below.

```
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
newPath = path + "/" + fileNameMobile;
File outFile = new File(newPath);

if(!outFile.exists()) {
    outFile.createNewFile(); // fails here
}
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
ImageHandler.copyFile(in, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
```

and newPath is

```
/storage/sdcard0/com.rahil.ecat/_5577d1b953e54351a4a7132252c11304.jpg
```

I can't find exactly why it fails on 1 device and works on the other 2 devices. Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Here's how I get the fileNameMoblie:

```
String fileNameMobile = _url.substring(_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

and get the path and pass it to function as below:

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, _Context.getPackageName());
```

and here's the result of outFile.getAbsolutePath():

```
/storage/sdcard0/com.rahil.ecat/_5577d1b953e54351a4a7132252c11304.jpg
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's the complete code:

Class ImageTask

```
public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

private Context _Context;
private String _token;
private ImageView _imageView;
private ProgressBar _pbar;
private String _url;
private HttpRequestHandler _hrh;
private ImageType _type;
private RoundedImageView _rImageView;

public ImageTask(Context context, String token, ImageView imageView, RoundedImageView rImageView, ImageType type) {
    this._Context = context;
    _token = token;
    _imageView = imageView;
    _type = type;
    _rImageView = rImageView;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    if(!_token.isEmpty())
    {
        File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, _Context.getPackageName());
        boolean found = false;
        String[] tokenParts = _token.split("\\.");
        String realToken = _token;
        if(tokenParts.length == 2)
        {
            realToken = tokenParts[0];
        }
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                String name = f.getName();

                if(name.contains(realToken))
                {
                    found = true;
                    if(Util.isMobile(name))
                    {
                        publishProgress(yourDir.getPath() + '/' + name, "NULL");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(Util.hasActiveInternetConnection(_Context)) {
                            getUrl();
                            if(!_url.isEmpty()) {
                                _hrh = new HttpRequestHandler(_url, _Context);
                                String fileName = _hrh.downloadImage(yourDir.getPath(), _token, true);
                                if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
                                    if(fileName.contains("-mob")) {
                                        f.delete();
                                    }
                                    publishProgress(fileName, "NULL");
                                } else {
                                    publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
                                }
                            }else {
                                publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            if(Util.hasActiveInternetConnection(_Context))
            {
                getUrl();
                if(!_url.isEmpty()) {
                    _hrh = new HttpRequestHandler(_url, _Context);
                    String fileName = _hrh.downloadImage(yourDir.getPath(), _token, false);
                    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        publishProgress(fileName, "NULL");
                    } else {
                        publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
                    }
                }else {
                    publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                publishProgress("", "DEFAULT");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loadDefaultImage();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    if(values[1].equals("DEFAULT"))
    {
        loadDefaultImage();
    }
    else
    {
        loadImage(values[0]);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void loadImage(String path)
{
    try {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        if (image != null) {
            if(_imageView != null) {
                StreamDrawable sd = null;
                if(_type == ImageType.BLUR)
                {
                    sd = new StreamDrawable(image, 10, 10);
                    _imageView.setBackground(sd);
                }
                else if(_type == ImageType.NO_EFFECT)
                {
                    _imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                }
            }
            else if(_rImageView != null) {
                _rImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        loadDefaultImage();
    }
}

private void getUrl()
{
    WebService ws = new WebService(_Context);
    _url = ws.getImageUrlForScreenTypeAndToken(
            _token,
            Util.getScreenType(_Context).name());
}

private void loadDefaultImage()
{
    if(_imageView != null) {
        _imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    }
    else if(_rImageView != null) {
        _rImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    }
}
}
```

Class HttpRequestHandler

```
public class HttpRequestHandler {

private String _url;
private Context _Context;
private ProgressDialog _dialog;

public HttpRequestHandler(String url, Context context) {
    _url = url;
    _Context = context;
}

public String  init_post(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    String data = null ;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        data = parser(response.getEntity());

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return data;
}

public String init() {
    String data = null ;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI(_url);
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        data = parser(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception t) {

        if(true)
        {
            String s = "asd";
        }
    }
    return data;
}

private String parser(HttpEntity entity){
    InputStream is = null;
    String jsonParse = "";
    try {
        is = entity.getContent();
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        jsonParse = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonParse;
}

public String downloadImage(String path, String token, boolean check) {
    String newPath = "";
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String fileNameMobile = _url.substring(_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if(check && token.equals(fileNameMobile))
        {
            return newPath;
        }
        URL urlConnection = new URL(_url);
        URLConnection connection = urlConnection.openConnection();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        newPath = path + "/" + fileNameMobile;
        File outFile = new File(newPath);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        ImageHandler.copyFile(in, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newPath;
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like a file name issue even though you say its not.  Double check you filename before creating it again.  Log it

Comment: @Xjasz that's what I did and I pasted it here from my log. That's the complete path and I can't see any illegal path in it, even though if there's anything wrong with the name then why it throws error on the 3rd device only ?

Comment: how are you getting the path? Storage locations are device specific, so if you hard-code /storage/sdcard0 that's probably the issue.

Comment: Does that other device have the same directory?  I'm thinking something about the directory could through the same error.

Comment: I'm guessing that other device is missing an sd card you should just save it like this

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: The directory is created on all devices.

Comment: Did you check [Environment.getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())?

Comment: Do not use createNewFile(). It serves nothing and makes your code unclear. The file will be created by the new FileOutputStream.

Comment: Please show how you come to `path` and `fileNameMobile`. Use a log statement to print outFile.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @greenapps I've updated my post, please check

Comment: Please build in a check to see that yourDir exists. And is writable. Please tell why the code would behave different on the rooted one. You are not using yourDir for outFile. Please post complete code with all checks in a new code block.

Comment: @greenapps I've edited the post, from Edit 2 is the 2 classes I'm using for all the checking, downloading, saving and assigning the image to imageview. Thanks for your support.

Comment: That is a ridiculous amount of code. I will not dig through that. And you are using strict mode which is not fine.

Answer (score 0):

This permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This code.

```
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
String filepath = getFilesDir().toString() + "/MyCustomFolder/";
File imagesFolder = new File(filepath);
if(!imagesFolder.exists())
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
File outFile = new File(filepath + "FileName.jpg");
if(!outFile.exists()){
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    ImageHandler.copyFile(in, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
}else{
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Then I am lost what is this device?  Are you trying to save to the SD card?  remove the underscore and shorten the file name.  I know you can use 255 characters but its obviously complaining.  You should just try to save a file called image.jpg if that should never kick off that error.

Comment: It's Lenovo A516 and it does have 4 GB of built in storage which doesn't allow anything to be saved on it so I had to insert a sd card to save images on other applications like viber etc... Could it be the reason ?

Comment: Don't save to the SD card then just save to an internal directory

Comment: You should keep that in mind when saving data to devices.  Not everyone has an SD card on their device.  Some people don't even know if they have an SD card.  I wrote some code to saving images to internal storage a while back let me find it for you

Comment: Check my edit above You will run into trouble saving to external storage.  External storage is good if you want to remember the users data after a full re-install of the app but why waste time with it just store whatever you need on your server.  Use Internal storage and if they really need to recover something store it on your server.  They can recover it from there.

Comment: Same here. Do not use createNewFile. Check the return value of mkdirs. Check canWrite() on the destination directory.  A write internal storage permission does not exist.

Comment: @Xjasz. Where are you talking about? You know there is internal, external and removable storage. The latter is a micro SD card.

Comment: @greenapps - I realize that sorry.  I wasn't thinking been busy on a project sorry for confusing you.  I was just saying have you tried saving to the internal storage?  Maybe the manufacturer didn't lockup the internal storage.  Honestly I want to know how many other devices do this because I save data to external storage on some apps.  If you know please let me know!  Try an internal save though and go that route for all saving if it lets you.

Comment: All devices allow to write to external storage. Why this rooted one does not allow it i dont know. But then the used code is incomplete, bad written and we really cant see what OP is trying.